# node js spawn cut result

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

I have this code in `node js` that execute a `java program` and read the `stdout`

```
let javaRun = spawn('java', execParam);
javaRun.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());               
});
```

It work well, in most situation, but in some situations the returned string is quite large (22700 chars in utf8), and when it's that large, console.log only print the first 8020 chars and cut the rest.

Is there a way to have an unlimited length of return for the string or at least a very large one?

Thank you

Comment: try to write it in a file ?

Comment: @AshBringer The problem is not on the console.log, even if I write it in on a file, I still only get the first 8020 chars

Comment: `.sustr` by multiples of 8020char until it return a empty string, print part by part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that .on('data') was called multipled time with chunks of the data.

So I modified the java to add an EOL tag each time I sysout something and look for it while reading the stdout.

Answer (score 0):

```
const CONSOLELOGLIMIT = 8020;
let s = 0, f = CONSOLELOGLIMIT, part = ' ';
strData = data.toString();
while(part.length > 0) {
    part = strData.substr(s, f);
    console.log(part);
    s = s + CONSOLELOGLIMIT;
    f = f + CONSOLELOGLIMIT;
}
```